# Is TCanvas.DrawLine() a vector draw or a pixel-based draw?

Tags: delphi

When I call `DrawLine()` on a `TImage.Bitmap.Canvas`, is it a vector draw or a pixel-based draw?

Comment: The VCL `TCanvas` is only a fairly thin wrapper around the Windows GDI interface from the late 80s. If you are dealing with bitmap images, they are entirely pixel based; no vector graphics here. But you can also draw to a printer's canvas or a metafile canvas, in which case you are using true vector graphics.

Comment: The metaFile canvas is just an object that I have to instanciate ? I'm a trainee and I'm learning Pascal and Delphi developpment, I'm not familiar with this tools. I'm Java based developper so many things are different for me

Comment: Yes, creating Windows metafiles (WMF or EMF files) in Delphi is very easy. If you Google it, you will find many, many simple examples on how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a pixel-based draw. If you need vector drawing, you may look at SVG components or use a metafile. Anyway, at some point, it will be rasterized to be rendered on screen or other device.

Comment: But if you are drawing on a metafile canvas, it is vector based. And if you are drawing to a printer, it is again vector based (I think). The point is that the `TCanvas` class is only an interface: you can use it to draw on both raster bitmaps and vector targets. But of course, in this case, the OP explicitly wrote `Bitmap.Canvas`, and then you are right.

Comment: I agree with you, but I'm a trainee, and SVG Components aren't free or open source, so I have to avoid this solution I think :/ Thanks for the help, maybe you have other tools that can do the same job ?

Comment: This is the answer to your question. It's not clear what tools you might be looking for, because we don't know what the problem is.

Comment: My job is to create an application that where I can draw 2 vector (in canvas or something that accept vector) and calculate the angle between this 2 vectors. Just that simple, but I don't know where and how I can draw vector with FMX components. As I said in an another post, I'm new in this environment so my question can be relative and not accurate enough for you to help me.

Comment: @FDA-PIOUPIOU There are OpenSource SVG components. Google is your friend: For example, try this search https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=delphi+svg+site%3Agithub.com

Comment: @fpiette Thanks, I'll take a look at this !

Comment: @FDA-PIOUPIOU You should edit your question to add more details, or open a completely new if your problem evolve. StackOverflow is not a chat...

Comment: FDA: Are you sure you know the difference between raster and vector graphics? You can certainly draw "vectors" (arrows) using raster graphics as well. Calculating an angle has absolutely nothing to do with drawing things on a screen.

Comment: Calculate the angle between two vectors and drawing the vectors are two different issues. Please create a new question with that, showing what you already have done and where you are blocked.

Comment: I think you are getting poor advice here. You don't need SVG for calculating angles.

Comment: David is right: what you need is a dot product (Google it!).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the question is about drawing, not angle calculation.

Comment: @fpiette: True. But there might be a possibility that the OP is confusing vector graphics with "arrows". You can draw vectors (arrows) even in a pixel-based environment!

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me ! I can only post every 90 minutes so I gonna recreate a post in an hour, with, hopefully, enough information for everyone